# Authorization Code Flow ВКонтакте для серверного приложения на Java

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, servlet, redirect

Хочу использовать API ВКонтакте для отправки сообщений от имени группы из веб-приложения (использую WildFly).
Из сервлета вызывается метод SendMessage, вот код:

```
public class VkMessageSender implements MessageSender{
    private static final Integer APP_ID = 123; // id приложения
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "..."; // защищенный ключ
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html";
    private static final String OAUTH_URI = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id="
            + APP_ID + "&display=page&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&redirect_uri="
            + REDIRECT_URI + "&scope=messages&response_type=code&v=5.68";
    private static final Integer GROUP_ID = 123; // id группы, из которой отправляются сообщения
    HttpServletResponse response; // получаем из сервлета
    TransportClient transportClient = HttpTransportClient.getInstance();
    VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);


    public void SendMessage(Integer user, String message) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect(OAUTH_URI);
        String code = response.getHeader("code");

        try {
            GroupAuthResponse authResponse = vk.oauth()
                    .groupAuthorizationCodeFlow(APP_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, code)
                    .execute();
            GroupActor actor = new GroupActor(GROUP_ID, authResponse.getAccessTokens().get(GROUP_ID));
            vk.messages().send(actor).message(message).userId(user);
        } catch (Throwable e){
            throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public VkMessageSender(HttpServletResponse response){
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Код успешно компилируется, после нажатия на кнопку браузер перенаправляется oauth.vk.com, в адресной строке вижу необходимый мне code. Но при этом никакое сообщение не отправляется, а в логах вижу:

```
2017-10-29 04:48:44,442 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-48) UT005023: Exception handling request to /sendmsg/blank.html: javax.servlet.ServletException: Internal API server error. Wrong status code: 401. Content: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code is invalid or expired."}
    at servletpackage.VkMessageSender.SendMessage(VkMessageSender.java:49)
    at servletpackage.MainServlet.doPost(MainServlet.java:20)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Что я делаю не так? Как мне правильно извлечь code из параметров GET-метода, которым ВК отвечает на мой редирект?

Comment: Декомпозируйте задачу. Попробуйте получить безлимитный по времени токен вручную в браузере, затем используйте его в при создании GroupActor. Еще по документации проверьте, нужно ли использовать отрицательный group_id, для многих методов отрицательный идентификатор является отличием от идентификатора пользователя.

Comment: Под безлимитным токеном вы подразумеваете ключ доступа из настроек сообщества?

Comment: С этим ключом заработало. Group_id отрицательный не нужен. После вызова send() и установки message и userId необходимо также вызвать execute(). И спасибо за наводку.